# Angular2 material 'md-icon' is not a known element with Karma / Jasmine

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine

I'm working on an Angular2 application using 
@angular/material 2.0.0-alpha.11-3
angular-cli 1.0.0-beta.19-3
karma 1.2.0
karma-jasmine 1.0.2

Running it works fine but a couple of the tests where the template has a button with md-icon fail with template errors:

```
ERROR: 'Unhandled Promise rejection:', 'Template parse errors:
'md-icon' is not a known element:
1. If 'md-icon' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.                                
2. If 'md-icon' is a Web Component then add "CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA" to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message
```

My app.module.ts:

```
import { MaterialModule } from '@angular/material';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    LinearProgressIndicatorComponent,
    MyNewDirectiveDirective,
    MyNewServiceDirective,
    HeaderComponent,
    MenuComponent,
    WatchpanelComponent,
    InputComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule,
    NgbModule.forRoot(),
    MaterialModule.forRoot(),
  ],
  exports: [ MaterialModule ],
  providers: [LocalStorage],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

watchpanel.component.spec.ts:

```
import { async, ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { By } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { DebugElement } from '@angular/core';
import { WatchpanelComponent } from './watchpanel.component';

describe('WatchpanelComponent', () => {
  let component: WatchpanelComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<WatchpanelComponent>;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ WatchpanelComponent ] // declare the test component
    })
    .compileComponents();

    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(WatchpanelComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();

  }));

  // beforeEach(() => {
  //   fixture = TestBed.createComponent(WatchpanelComponent);
  //   component = fixture.componentInstance;
  //   fixture.detectChanges();
  // });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

As I understood it @angular/material now contains the only module needed to import, MaterialModule. I tried importing the MdIconModule from @angular2-material/icon with no success. What am i doing wrong ?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Importing the MaterialModule as suggested by yurzui and creating the component after the promise is returned solved it. Thank you yurzui

```
import { async, ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { By } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { DebugElement } from '@angular/core';
import { WatchpanelComponent } from './watchpanel.component';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { MaterialModule } from '@angular/material';

describe('WatchpanelComponent', () => {
  let component: WatchpanelComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<WatchpanelComponent>;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [ MaterialModule.forRoot() ],
      // forRoot() deprecated
      // in later versions ------^
      declarations: [ WatchpanelComponent ] // declare the test component
    })
    .compileComponents().then(() => {
      fixture = TestBed.createComponent(WatchpanelComponent);
      component = fixture.componentInstance;
      fixture.detectChanges();
    });

  }));

  // beforeEach(() => {
  //   fixture = TestBed.createComponent(WatchpanelComponent);
  //   component = fixture.componentInstance;
  //   fixture.detectChanges();
  // });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

Answer (score 7):

Things've changed in newer versions of Angular Material since @javahaxxor's answer. I've resolved this problem with importing same modules as I do in `AppModule` (I also need Forms here):

```
import {
  MatButtonModule,
  MatCardModule,
  MatIconModule,
  MatInputModule,
  MatProgressSpinnerModule,
  MatDialogModule,
  MatCheckboxModule
} from '@angular/material';

// ... not important

beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ WelcomeComponent ],
      imports: [
        NoopAnimationsModule,
        FormsModule,
        ReactiveFormsModule,
        MatButtonModule,
        MatCardModule,
        MatIconModule,
        MatInputModule,
        MatProgressSpinnerModule,
        MatDialogModule,
        MatCheckboxModule
      ],
      providers: [
        // ...
      ]
    })
    .compileComponents();
  }));
```

Answer (score 6):

*md-icon* is no longer available in the latest versions of Angular Material. All tags/elements are now prefixed with "mat" instead of "md".. So `<md-icon>` ..becomes.. `<mat-icon>`